# How to get facebook app approved on App center?

Tags: facebook, facebook-apps, review

I have submitted our facebook app for App center review, but it has been in pending status for 10 days, according to facebook App center guideline http://developers.facebook.com/docs/appcenter/guidelines/ "Once it has **enough positive ratings and engagement**, we will automatically review your app detail page and contact you if any changes are needed before it appears in a category."

Could anyone please tell me after a facebook app submitted for review, how to get enough positive ratings and engagement? What is exact rating/engagement amount? Where can I see the progress? Any facebook app center contact email?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Not to disappoint you, but we had our app being reviewed for 4 months and 11 days before our patience ran out. We had 50K users and 400 5* ratings out of 450 total ratings. It is insane how irresponsible FB is regarding reviewing content. We resubmitted the app for review and it took several days before the app was live in App Center.

Positive ratings is when users that installed your app rate it from 1 to 5 stars. Engagement is basically how many users installed your app in total and how many did not remove it within short period of time (the more the better). There is no exact amount, but for example 10K new installs in first week is better than 10K installs in first year, yet the number is the same. Same goes for the progress bar - Facebook has its internal metrics. Good luck with review.

Comment: Thanks @Xeos , we just give up trying and put more focus on product.

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer. My application just recently approved but when i visit related directory i don't see it there.

Answer (score 2):

We are unable to submit the application page / details for review in the App Center, because

"Your app does not have high enough ratings and user engagement to be reviewed for the App Center at this time".

I asked some questions about this:

1) How can we improve ratings without being listed in the Facebook App Center?
2) Our user engagement is about the same level as other apps in the same category, which are published in the App Center. What is a critical mass to be eligible for review? Which numbers are relevant?

The response I got from a Facebook developer:

1) We randomly ask users that uses your app to rate it.
2) There are no specific number. Our algorithm takes in as much data as possible and try to figure out if it is a high quality app. But in general if you get bad review you need more active users, And if you have good reviews you need less.

**Update:**

In our case, we had to disable the web and mobile web implementation in the App details section, because they had too few users (so only Android/iOS was still enabled - our main applications). After that we got approved.

Answer (score 1):

The process for submission app is very tough. We need to strictly follow the guidelines. We need to sure what type of App we are developing and list of permissions are needed. Due to spamming by many Facebook App developers, Facebook app center required exact reason to get approve the required permission.

Here is an example of submission guidelines.

```
Tags

There may be scenarios where your app's users want to tag a friend. This tagging capability comes in two forms. One scenario is if the user takes an action with the friend (i.e. cooks a pizza with someone), and the other scenario is when the user simply wants to mention a friend (i.e. "Hey John Smith, let's make a pizza next time"). If you choose to choose to support both action and mention tags, clearly distinguish the two different use cases in your submission.

Action tagging appends "- with Friend" to the story.

Mention tagging allows your app's users to tag friends names within their user messages.
```

App Center Guidelines [App Center Guidelines link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/appcenter/guidelines)

Submission process https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/submission-process

Please go through the submission guidelines as well. I hope this will help anyone.

Answer (score 0):

I could upload two of my apps to App Center but now as though I don't have the correct gaming type option to be able to upload one